# Regex to allow * only after a certain position in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input field in the UI which must satisfy the following three conditions.

1. The input string can be a max of 20 chars long and will be alphanumeric.
2. However it can have * but only after 6th character, no other special characters allowed.

   Eg. Abc123* or Abc1234* or just Abc1234(until 20 chars)
3. The overall length of string is 20 chars but as soon as we encounter * we should not allow any further characters

I understand the 3rd condition can be a bit too much of an ask for regex and I should be able to handle that using javascript.
However I at least want to get the first 2 conditions resolved using regex.

I have tried few stuffs below but they don’t give the desired results:

```
export function formatInput(value) {
  return value
        .replace(/[^\w*]|_/g, '')
        .replace(new RegExp('(^[\\w]{6})([\\w*]{14}$)’, 'g'), '$1');
}
```

I tried to tweak few things, like if I remove the first replace statement it doesn’t filter out any special characters at all.

Also in the below case it restricts me to enter * as 7th character before allowing me to proceed further which is also incorrect.

```
export function formatInput(value) {
  return value
      .replace(/[^\w*]|_/g, '')
      .replace(new RegExp('(^[\\w]{6})[\\w]', 'g'), '$1')
      .replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')
      .replace(new RegExp('(\\*[\\w]{14}).', 'g'), '$1');
}
```

I am trying to enhance my knowledge about regex, so my above attempts might not be correct, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is `*` part of the 20 char limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
/^(?:[a-z\d]{6,19}\*|[a-z\d]{1,20})$/gmi
```

- `^` - start line anchor
- `(?:` - start non-capturing group

  - `[a-z\d]{6,19}\*` - we can have 6 to 19 alphanums followed by one asterisk
  - `|` - boolean or
  - `[a-z\d]{1,20}` - we can have 1 to 20 alphanums
- `)` - end non-capturing group
- `$` - end line anchor
- `/gmi` - flags: global, multiline, case-insensitive

  - `g` and `m` are only needed for regex101 purposes so that you can test out multiple inputs at once

https://regex101.com/r/ytMlQO/1/

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit confused with your attempt to replace, so let me just share a pattern that should tick the 3 boxes you described:

```
^(?!.{21}|.{1,5}\*)[A-Za-z\d]+\*?$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GNMtK5/1/)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?!.{21}|.{1,5}\*)` - Negative lookahead with alternation to prevent position is followed by 21 characters or 1-5 characters before the asterisks.
- `[A-Za-z\d]+` - 1+ Alphanumeric chars.
- `\*?` - An optional asterisks.
- `$` - End line anchor.

---

Note that you could also use case-insensitive flag as an alternative and use `^(?!.{21}|.{1,5}\*)[A-Z\d]+\*?$`.

Comment: I also use Regex101

Comment: `^(?!.{1,5}\*)[A-Za-z\d]{1,19}[A-Za-z\d*]$` fails for single char inputs: https://regex101.com/r/R5DiZw/1

Comment: Sharp eye @MonkeyZeus. I think I'll just remove that option alltogether =)

Answer (score 2):

The following pattern satisfies all your conditions. This pattern assumes there is no other content in `value` aside from the password to be checked. I also share the concern about performing manipulations a la `replace` in a function that is supposed to be purely for verification, so I've written the function below to simply test to ensure conformance with the prescribed pattern.

```js
const passwordPattern = /^[A-Za-z\d]{6}(?:[A-Za-z\d]|\*(?!.+)){0,14}$/;
const checkPassword = value => passwordPattern.test(value);

console.log(checkPassword("Abc123"));  // true
console.log(checkPassword("Abc123*")); // true
console.log(checkPassword("Abc12*")); // false - asterisk appears before position 6
console.log(checkPassword("Abc123*4")); // false - other characters appear after asterisk
console.log(checkPassword("123456789012345678901")); // false - >20 characters in length
```

[<sup>Regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/JjzQmT/1)

Comment: Bullet point #1 states that the input must be alphanum, `\w` is not restrictive enough. Yes, I know OP used it in their attempt but it's wrong per their requirements bullet list.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks, that's right - I've edited `\w` to now be more restrictive as `A-Za-z`

Comment: The |_  after [^\w*] restricts underscore in the #1. Not sure if i may be missing any other special characters. Also the replace was to just to remove the incorrect character immediately and replace it with ' ', but i can do without replace as well. Thanks a lot for all of your inputs